# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward. Response already committed

Tags: java, security, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

I want to redirect to the logOut url in filter,when some condition occurs.

I tried `sendRedirect` and `forward` method of `requestDispatcher`...but getting this error. I have commented the sendredirect Code.

```
if(){
    res.setHeader("fsd", "FAILURE");
    res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    /*res.sendRedirect("/searchReleaseLockLogout");*/                    
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/searchReleaseLockLogout").forward(req, res);
    return;
}
```

Comment: any solution for the above one??

Answer (score 0):

When invoke sendError on response, the response is already committed. Check documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int,%20java.lang.String)).Use [setStatus](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus(int)) instead.

Change,

```
 res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
```

to

```
 res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
```